# Class-based-views - Pulling together multiple models using FormView

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to build a Survey App. I have defined a model for Survey, Questions, Responses as below.

What I want to do is create a Survey (in admin, which I can do) then display this Survey as a page which users can fill in.

I'm using Class Based Views for the first time and I'm stuck with how to render the Survey form along with the associated Questions and allow input of Answers.

In Admin, I've created a Survey and successfully added Questions to it. FormView (and UpdateView, tried as part of another SO answer) allows me to display the Survey model's 'name' and 'description' attributes - but the questions don't appear.

What do I need to do to make the Survey and it's Questions available in my form (and allow the user to enter a response)?

MODELS

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

    def survey_questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()

class Response(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(user_model, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class AnswerBase(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class AnswerText(AnswerBase):
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

URLS

```
urlpatterns = [path('survey/<int:pk>/', views.SurveyResponseView.as_view(), name='survey_detail')]
```

VIEWS

```
class SurveyResponseView(FormView):
    template_name = 'survey/survey_detail.html'
    form_class = ResponseForm
```

FORMS

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the way to do this is to use [FormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/). They're a bit of a faff to setup, but shouldn't take you too long. I recommend using [this small js library to help](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset).

I also rewrote some of your code to hopefully make life a bit easier for you:

models.py

```
class SurveyTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    # You were missing this I believe
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()


class Question(models.Model):
    # Now you can do SurveyTemplate.questions.all()
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    question = models.TextField()


class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(user_model, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Answer(models.Model):
    # Now you can do Question.answers.all()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    # Now you can do Response.answers.all()
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView


# CreateView is Django's built in View for creating an object, you would be best to use it
class SurveyResponseView(CreateView):
    model = Survey
    template = 'survey/survey_detail.html'
    form_class = ResponseForm
```

forms.py

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I'm currently looking at FormSets, so maybe I don't see the whole picture yet, but are you sure that "CreateView" (for `SurveyResponseView`) is the correct generic view to use? When I click through to fill in the `ResponseForm` (127.0.01/survey/0), I can see the fields belonging to the `Survey` model (`name`, `description`, `published_date`). I'd like the user to fill in `Answer` fields instead of `Survey` fields. I'm assuming I will disable editing of `Survey` fields later, and through FormSets, display `Questions` and `Answers`, correct? Just want to be sure - CBVs are a bit confusing

Comment: Yeah so you then need to use formsets to add the various Answer objects to the view. Have you implemented something like this:

https://medium.com/@taranjeet/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

His guide is quite good.